# JQuery Selectable Widget Values Server Side ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I have been searching around on Google and SO for awhile now and can't seem to find an answer to this seemingly easy question.  I want to implement the JQuery selectable widget exactly how it is shown here:  http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#default.  I am using ASP.NET.  What I want to happen is the user will select every item they want from the list, whether it is one or multiple items.  When they are done, they will click a submit button.  My question is how can I see what values are selected server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [serialize](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#serialize) example.

Use the `stop` event to create a list of values, put that list in an hidden field control, and read the list on the server.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for that, it was right in front of me haha.

Comment: Still the answer in 2023.